# Add a chess position rendering engine

Tags: feature-request, chess

As we are probably going to deal with chess puzzles in the future, I thought it'd be nice if we could have some feature for displaying chess puzzles, ideally the same feature they have on Chess SE.

**Main reasons:**

- *No need for images* (taking multiple screenshots/uploading hand-drawn art)
- Positions can be played (with comments and branches)
- Position can be *changed* (adjustments of errors)

**Exemplary list of posts on our SE which would benefit from such a feature (feel free to edit in more of these):**

- [Find the color of the chess pieces](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/603/find-color-of-the-chess-pieces)
- [Most moveable chess position](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/most-moveable-chess-position)
- [What is the position in chess with the longest string of moves before mate?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/550/what-is-the-position-in-chess-with-the-longest-string-of-moves-before-mate)
- [How many queens can be on a chessboard without attacking each other?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-many-queens-can-be-on-a-chessboard-without-attacking-each-other) (poster chose to draw the position himself/herself)
- [How many squares can 4 queens control?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/462/how-many-squares-can-4-queens-control) (maybe)
- [How many chess pieces does it take to "cover" all spaces on a chessboard?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22/how-many-chess-pieces-does-it-take-to-cover-all-spaces-on-a-chessboard)
- My next two questions.

**Here's a simple FEN markup example:**

"How to avoid checkmate for one more move"

```
[FEN "r1bqkb1r/pppp1Qpp/2n2n2/4p3/2B1P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNB1K1NR b KQkq - 0 0"]

1...Kxf7 2.Bxf7
```

Comment: Sounds good to me, but (like mathjax) the team is likely to ask us to assemble a list of questions that would benefit from it.

Comment: @Kevin here you go.

Answer (score 5):

I think a chess rendering engine on puzzling.SE is a good idea. The common practice here now for displaying a chess game is to create an animated .gif image. These are frustrating because they often move so fast it's impossible to think about what's going on.

Since the technology already exists on the SE network, I imagine the cost of implementing it here is small.

Answer (score 1):

d'alar'cop recently posted [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/do-we-want-built-in-chess-features)

> I found out that Chess.SE has a nice chess rendering feature - see an example [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/do-we-want-built-in-chess-features).

to reopen this discussion. It was closed, because this posting here existed already, so I'm going to use this to renew the discussion.

---

I am **against** a specific chess-rendering feature. And the reason is:

It would be an open invitation to post countless chess-puzzles, and *most* of them will then be closed as **"..this posting would be better suited at Chess.SE..."** I think if a dedicated SE sites already exists and additionally has the feature, it is not worthwhile to do the same here. If something on Chess.SE becomes too much of a *puzzle* for people there, they can always put a link up, can't they?

Indeed, any chess puzzle that wouldn't belong chess would probably be unconventional or unreal situations (like any number of queens at all, or new hypothetical pieces) - and any standardised chess-rendering would never help with these.

*BTW, what happens if a question is 'migrated' from one site to the other and one has a specific makeup language feature, the other hasn't ??*

Comment: Yep, I have actually been convinced that we don't need it.

Comment: I honestly doubt the lack of replayer is why there are not "countless chess-puzzles" already posted here. There certainly aren't that many posted on Chess.se.