# Do we want built-in chess features?

Tags: feature-request, chess

I found out that Chess.SE has a nice chess rendering feature - see an example [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7607/how-to-make-a-computer-play-like-a-player).

I also noticed that this issue has come up in the past as though it were a brand new idea - see [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/add-a-chess-position-rendering-engine).

Is this something we could integrate? (I can think of many instances where this would have been useful for many people in the recent past)

I would agree with the declaration of duplicate... however the other question does **not** have an answer. I'm not sure what protocol is in this case.

Comment: @Doorknoob actually it doesn't have an answer

Comment: I think the suggestion would be to use the old question to renew the discussion. I'm going to answer there.